# How to find out which react component throws empty props error

Tags: reactjs

I am using react v15.1 and it's got this small change where null value props throws the following error:

[image: react warning us of null value]

The console log isn't very helpful, what's a better way to find out in which component this null value props is located?

Thank you

Comment: I think the prop name is *value*

Comment: Can you click the link to line 9779 and see which component it's referring to?

Comment: Place a breakpoint in where `mountComponent` is shown at the topmost of its occurrence in the stack trace. It will fire too much but you can use a confditional breakpoint to help with that. Figure out what the conditions in the code for a warning is, and use those conditions to only stop at the appropriate moment, and then when you break there you should be able to look around and see which component was being worked with

Comment: @Kishore Barik, that's right, though, I have many components which take a value prop so having to hunt them down one by one would take a long time, so I wonder if there is a shortcut to finding which component specifically gets passed this null value prop

Comment: @MattDuFeu it gives a very generic console.log(message) line that's clear that it's part of the react library; I clicked through a few more lines in the error messages but none of them indicated which component is in question.

Answer (score 1):

Future versions of React will treat  as a request to clear the input. However, React 0.14 has been ignoring value={null}. React 15 warns you on a null input value and offers you to clarify your intention. To fix the warning, you may explicitly pass an empty string to clear a controlled input, or pass undefined to make the input uncontrolled.
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html

Details is here https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/5048/commits

You can either use breakpoint or manually check all components that have input, select or textarea  within the page

Comment: Thanks, I did read that page, but I am stumped to find that there is no easy way to identify, among my dozens of components that do include an input field, which one was the main offender. As you mention and I suspect, one has to go through all inputs to put out the fire. A less than ideal situation.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, this is without a doubt the most frustrating part to React development for me.